# how do i predict my machine translation after i loaded model.5

Tags: python-3.x, keras, model, prediction, machine-translation

i had build seq2seq translation with keras it is translating between 2 languages

then i saved the whole model as model.h5

```
  model.save('model.h5')
```

and then i loaded the **model.h5** in another python script

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.h5')
model.summary()
m = model.get_weights()
print(m)
```

and i can see the summary and the weights of my model

but i do not know how to make a prediction.

i translated english to french

now i want input english and see the prediction of french

how can i do it ? any idea is it really that hard or impossible?

**Updated**

i tried this but gives me an error

```
text = np.array(['how can i solve this question'])
print(text.shape)

res = model.predict(text)
```

**Error**

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to
>   have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the prediction of a model using

```
predicted_output = model.predict(input)
```